# Change CGImageDestination dpi

Tags: objective-c, dpi, cgimage, nsimagerep

I know how to change the dpi of a NSImageRep, but I can't figure out how to make CGImage APIs reflect this change... Is there a way to make CGImage write a file which is NOT a standard 72dpi? If I set a NSImageRep to be 144dpi, when I write it to file using CGImage APIs I always obtain a 72dpi image...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add an image to your destination with `CGImageDestinationAddImage`, you can pass a dictionary as the `properties` parameter. For this dictionary you can use all the keys specified in the [CGImageProperties Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html), specifically `kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth` and `kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight`.

Comment: Genius! You've indirectly answered to another question I posted a few hours ago: I asked why CGImage doesn't accept 1024px reps anymore in MacOS 10.7.4: now I know it accepts 1024px reps but ONLY if they have a resolution of 144dpi. Thank you very much!